# Duplicate column name and mutli-part identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a query with a few `JOIN` statements and a pair of column names that are identical. In trying to solve this, I'm now getting the following errors

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "v_parametersets.NAME" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "catalog.NAME" could not be bound.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
   startedon, 
   endedon, 
   v_parametersets.name As Parameter, 
   catalog.name As Category, 
   status, 
   numberprocessed, 
   errormessage 
FROM
    Prod.dbo.status ps 
INNER JOIN 
    Prod.dbo.v_parametersets vps ON bps.parametersetid = vps.parametersetid 
INNER JOIN 
    Prod.dbo.catalog pc ON ps.catalogid = pc.id 
WHERE  
    ps.endedon BETWEEN Dateadd(hh, -3, Sysdatetime()) AND Sysdatetime()
```

So there's a column called `name` on the table `catalog` and a column called `name` on the view `v_parametersets`. I need both of these, but the multi-part identifier can't be bound for some reason.

Comment: you aliased the tables so use the alis name instead of the view/table name.

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aliased the tables, you have to use the alias name when describing the selected columns/field names, you can't reference the table name due to the fact the compiler has already aliased the table and no longer has knowledge of the original table name.  The name has basically fallen out of the scope as the joins have been completed and the joins resolved with temporary storage created using the alias names.

Put another way you told the system to change the name of Prod.dbo.v_parametersets to VPS in step 1.
In step 4 you referenced the name of an object you changed in step 1.  The system no longer knows that name (for the scope of this query), you changed it!

```
SELECT startedon, 
   endedon, 
   VPS.name As Parameter,   <--This line
   PC.name As Category,   <--This line
   status, 
   numberprocessed, 
   errormessage 
FROM   Prod.dbo.status ps 
   INNER JOIN Prod.dbo.v_parametersets vps 
           ON bps.parametersetid = vps.parametersetid 
   INNER JOIN Prod.dbo.catalog pc 
           ON ps.catalogid = pc.id 
WHERE  ps.endedon BETWEEN Dateadd(hh, -3, Sysdatetime()) AND Sysdatetime()
```

Comment: The reason that the query processor can't use the table names is that it can't known which table to use if a single table is used multiple times in a single query.